# How to find new individuals in repeated surveys with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have data with uniquely identified individuals, in groups, which were surveyed multiple times. Sometimes new individuals showed up after the first survey, and I want to find those new individuals by group. E.g.,

```
group <- rep(1:2, each=9)
surv <- c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3) 
ind <- c("a","b","a","b","c","a","b","c","d",  "a","b","c", "a", "b","c","d", "a","b")
dat <- data.table(surv=surv, group=group, ind=ind)
setkey(dat, surv, group)
```

I want a new data table with the new inviduals i.e.,

```
survey 2, group 1, "c"
survey 2, group 2, "d"
survey 3, group 1, "d"
```

I'm flummoxed by this, which the following starter code shows:

```
dat[surv==2, !(ind %in% surv==1), by = group]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the first survey each individual appeared in each group,

```
dat[order(ind, surv), .SD[1], .(group, ind)][surv != 1]
#>    group ind surv
#> 1:     1   c    2
#> 2:     2   d    2
#> 3:     1   d    3
```

Note I've excluded the individuals who first appeared in the first survey.

Answer (score 0):

The `duplicated` function lets you know where a value appears first.

```
dat[!duplicated(ind), ]
#    surv group ind
# 1:    1     1   a
# 2:    1     1   b
# 3:    1     2   c
# 4:    2     2   d
```